# how to store a file in a char*

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

**My question** is : how can I store the content of a .txt file in a `char*` named m_str, in C++?

Kindly note that my file has a very defined format that I want to keep. I don't want to merge the lines together. I want what is one line 1 to stay on line 1, and what is one line 2 to stay in line 2.  Because eventually I am going to serialize that `char*` and send it over the network, and when a node receives it, it will deserialize it and then put the content in a file and read the lines as they were in the original file.

Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975931/read-from-file-as-char-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use vector as:

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> begin(file), end;
std::vector<char> v(begin, end); //it reads the entire file into v

char *contentOfTheFile= &v[0];
```

The content of the file is stored in `contentOfTheFile`. You can use it, and *modify* it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

void foo() {
  std::ifstream stream("file.txt");
  if (!stream) throw std::runtime_error("could not open file.txt.");
  std::vector<char> str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream),
                        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
  char* m_str = str.data();
}
```

Should do what you need.

Comment: That is not going to work. `str` is not an object; it is a function declaration. Reason ; C++ vexing parse!

Comment: `std::vector<char> str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream));` is a function declaration :) [Fortunately](http://ideone.com/arRRm), the compiler can catch the error, because you are using the parameter name `stream` twice.