# How to Reverse Quine?

Tags: c, quine

i have written a C programme which prints itself n times, but i can't get how to reverse print the same n times.E.g, if the sample programme is :

```
hello
```

then the required output should be `"olleh" for n=1`.
Here's my quine programme,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n;
  char c;
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen(__FILE__,"r");
  scanf("%d",&n);
 while(n--)
 {
 while((c=getc(f))!=EOF)
 putchar(c);
 fseek(f,0,0);
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it's considered cheating if you read from disk with a quine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to read the file into an array (like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410943/reading-a-text-file-into-an-array-in-c)), and then just reverse the array:

```
void swap(char* a, char* b) {
  char tmp = *b;
  *b = *a;
  *a = tmp;
}

void reverse(char* arr, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) {
    swap(arr+i, arr + (size - (i + 1)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a pure quine. See [the Quine article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)):

> A quine takes no input. Allowing input
>   would permit the source code to be fed
>   to the program via the keyboard,
>   opening the source file of the
>   program, and similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this post.
Here is sample reverse quine in C, that i made. You can modify it to suit your needs!

```
a="};)01(rahctup;)--p*(rahctup);p*;43=p*(rof;)a(ftnirp;))a,b=p(tacrts(nelrts=+p{)p*rahc(niam;}7393422{=]99[b;";b[99]={2243937};main(char*p){p+=strlen(strcat(p=b,a));printf(a);for(*p=34;*p;)putchar(*p--);putchar(10);}
```