# C++ Something better than fgetc?

Tags: c++, performance, fgetc

I have a huge file, which I'm reading with fopen & fgetc in a loop.

It takes around 6 seconds to read the entire file with "rb" flag in fopen, there are around 25k lines in the file.

I was wondering; what are faster ways than fgetc ? is it better to first load everything in a char* array ? is strcpy better ?

- note that It's better if it's the way fgetc, or if I'm able to at least get char by char in the array.
- what's are better ways than fgetc ?

Comment: [fread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html)?

Comment: First of all, C or C++?

Comment: Title says C++, so C++

Comment: Generally, reading bigger chunks is better. Also take a look at `fgetc_unlocked`, if your implementation provides it.

Comment: [`std::getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) can be implemented as a macro (which I find funny considering its namespace-qualified). This is intentional (the macro part)  it has the benefit of potentially reducing the invoke-overhead unless a buffer refill is required. Worth a try to bench it (in **release** build, of course). And I concur with Deduplicator, front-lock the file and don't forget to unlock it when finished.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are really absolutely sure it can be implemented as a macro (and not only as an inline function) in C++ too, and not only in C?

Comment: Reading a each character in a loop is going to be slower than reading the whole file into memory or even a chunk at a time. So, are you reading the whole file, or just part of it and do you need to read one character at a time?

Comment: fgetc_unlocked & std::getc gave the same result in bechmark speed, 6 seconds.

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro on a release build? (gotta ask).

Comment: Perhaps this is what you really want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410943/reading-a-text-file-into-an-array-in-c

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, release build.

Comment: @Merlin069 **char \*bytes = malloc (pos);** void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char*

Comment: Well thats odd, because when I flockfile + getc() through EOF (saving in a contiguous memory buffer) + funlockfile on a 32MB disk file read in binary-mode i'm at 683ms (yes, its an SSD). removing the flockfile/funlockfile brackets pushes the same code up to 2360ms. And using `fgetc` only rachets it up another 150ms or so, so I'm with Deduplicator on this.

Comment: malloc returns a void*, so cast it to a char* with char* bytes = (char*)malloc(pos);

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro if you're man-handling the entire file, at least use a `std::vector<char>`. `malloc` has no place in a modern C++ program.

Comment: @WhozCraig **flockfile** is unrecognized on my code, what header file is it on?

Comment: [**See here**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/flockfile.3.html)

Comment: @WhozCraig having the buffer in a std::vector ? will it be faster than fgetc ?

Comment: The purpose of the vector-owned buffer is to [avoid pointers owning resources.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf). That in the event you decide to bulk-load it.

Comment: On POSIX-compliant systems, mmap() will achieve the "access character by character" requirement. Let the OS deal with memory allocation and I/O buffering; those are things it is good at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire problem with my code was that I was using fget_pos and fset_pos everytime I wanted to "return" a char, there was ungetc which significantly increases speed!

Answer (score 1):

Well fgetc is already pretty much optimized, because it uses the underlying buffering of fopen. Simply you call a function (but not a system call) for each character. You could try to increase the buffer size (as you say you are reading huge files) with setbuffer :

```
#define SIZE 65536
// or use even greater size if appropriate ...
char buffer[SIZE];

fd = fopen(...);
setbuffer(fd, buffer, SIZE);
```

Alternatively, do you need do read character per character ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a textual file, it is probably made of reasonably sized lines. Then you may try to read it line by line, e.g. with [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) (or, in C, [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html))

If you are on a Posix system e.g. Linux, you could use low-level [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Be sure to have large enough buffers of e.g. 16Kbytes or 64KBytes.

BTW, if on Linux, try `time wc yourbigfile`, it should give you an idea of a lower-bound of the time actually needed to read your file. Remember that there is a file system cache: see http://linuxatemyram.com/ for more.

<sup>on my Linux desktop system `wc` of a 6Mbytes, 100Klines file takes about 0.1 second realtime.</sup>

Perhaps read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), at least if you run your program on Posix systems.

<sup>BTW, your question is operating system and perhaps file system specific.</sup>